# Adobe Air and PHP

Tags: php, xml, flex3, air, amfphp

i do not fully understand how to communicate between adobe air (using flex3) and php. i do understand that many use AMFPHP and Zend AMF.

However, AMFPHP seems to be outdated and Zend AMF (from what i understand) only works with the Zend framework (something I dont use, nor like IMHO).

My Question Is:
Are there other ways of communication besides these. I know that one can use xml to do this, but is it efficient? can i use xml to INSERT INTO mysql tables?

Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMFPHP might be 'old' but it is incredibly functional and does its job well. The reason it isn't updated is because it doesn't really need to be. [WebORB is another option](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php/overview.html). WebORB is badass. Highly recommend you check it out.

Some other options:

- XML (REST style service)
- JSON Standard Javascript object notation

AMF is far and away superior to either of these solutions. It is faster, smaller transfer sizes, and you don't have to dink around with conversions on either side. The server and the client speak in native typed objects, not generic ASCII data types.

Answer (score 0):

You say :

> Zend AMF (from what i understand) only
>   works with the Zend framework

That is not true : `Zend_Amf` can be downloaded, and used, as a standalone package, without having to deal with the rest of Zend Framework.

See : [Zend Amf Download](http://framework.zend.com/download/amf)